# How to conditionally copy data from various places in overview using Google Apps Script based on a phrase?

Tags: google-apps-script, database-design

I am trying to figure out how to copy two sets of columns from one sheet to another in the same spreadsheet. This should only happen if it matches a certain phrase or word.

My source sheet contains a wide overview of people, who are divided into groups, such as swimming and football. Withing the groups, the people are further divided into projects, *e.g*. teens and under 10s.

The things I want to be copied are the names (preferably concatenated and separated by a space) which are in A4:B in the Overview sheet, the project they are working on (columns K and N), and their roles in the swimming group (columns L and O). [Simplified overview sheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjFS6.png)

In my target sheet, I am looking for a table. Names of swimming volunteers in the first column, project (such as teens and under 10s) in the second column, and their role (treasurer, orange-slice provider) in the last column. [Like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IH7d.png)

Below the script I have been working on. It doesn't work, I think because of the && in weird places.

```
function swimmingVolunteers() {
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Swimming");
  var targetLastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  var targetSwimming = targetSheet.getRange(2, 4, targetLastRow - 3, 2).getValues();

  // source of data
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Overview"); 
  var sourceLastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  // groups are in range equivalent to J4:J and M4:M
  var sourceGroupCheck = sourceSheet.getRange(4, 10, sourceLastRow - 1, 1 && 4, 13 sourceLastRow - 1, 1).getValues();
  // reference information range to be copied: A4:B (preferably concatenated and separated by a space), K4:L and N4:O
  var sourceRangeGroupInfo = sourceSheet.getRange(4, 1, sourceLastRow - 1, 2 && 4, 11, sourceLastRow - 1, 2 && 4, 14, sourceLastRow - 1, 2).getValues();
 
  var output = [];
  targetGroupCheck.forEach(function (targetGroup) {
    // search sourceGroupCheck for "swimming" 
    var index = searchForArray(sourceGroupCheck, "swimming");
    // if "swimming" is in sourceRangeGroupInfo, save the data on that row for later
    if (index > -1)
      output.push(sourceRangeGroupInfo[index]);
  });
  // if it was found, copy data to target document in column
  if (output.length > 0) {
    targetSheet.getRange(2, 3, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
    // with source A4:B in targetSheet column C (preferably concatenated and separated by a space),
    // source K and N in targetSheet column D, and
    // source L and O in targetSheet column E
  }
}
```

How would you go about this?

Comment: It would be easier for us to test your code if you provide a sample spreadsheet. It is difficult to determine which is `(columns K and N)` and `(columns L and O)` in your screenshot.

Comment: Clearly you do not understand the Sheet.getRange() method

Comment: The whole point of a [mcve] is so that we can reproduce the problem.  Therefore there cannot be any undefined variable or functions.  At a minimum I see that your missing `searchForArray(sourceGroupCheck, "swimming")`.  Please do your homework.